# Angular:Why is constructor parameters without access specifier not visible outside constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I explicitly specify access specifier for constructor parameter it is visible outside constructor
ex:

```
constructor(private employeResourceService:EmployeeResourceService ){
//code}
 ngOnInit(){
    this.employeResourceService=undefined;//possible

  }
```

but when I remove acces specifier ,constructor parameters are not visible outside constructor
ex:

```
 constructor(employeResourceService:EmployeeResourceService ){
    //code}
     ngOnInit(){
        this.employeResourceService=undefined;//not visible

      }
```

Why is this happening? TypeScript do not have a default access specifier like Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Giving an access specifier to a function parameter is none sense. In *TypeScript*, you can do this anyway to the constructor, and the meaning is the following: when you write

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(private employeResourceService: EmployeeResourceService){
    //code
  }
}
```

this is actually a shortcut for

```js
class MyClass {
  private employeResourceService: EmployeeResourceService
  constructor(employeResourceService: EmployeeResourceService){
    this.employeResourceService = employeResourceService
    //code
  }
}
```

So, in a single instruction, you have defined an instance parameter and have affected it with the parameter value. This shortcut only works if you give an access specifier. If you don't, it becomes a simple function parameter, which is neither declared as an instance parameter nor affected to anything.

Anyway, there is a default access value, but to use it, you have to declare the instance parameter, and affect it yourself:

```js
class MyClass {
  employeResourceService: EmployeeResourceService
  constructor(employeResourceService: EmployeeResourceService){
    this.employeResourceService = employeResourceService
    //code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That is on purpose, to make the code less verbose: adding an access modifier to the input param in the constructor is a short format of declaring the field on the class, passing the param in the constructor, and then assigning it to the class field.

And it is actually documented: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

EDIT: Typescript *does* have a default mode of input params: that is for when you only need the input param in the constructor, but not later. A good example for that is the `FormBuilder` which you usually don't store in a field, because you only need it once.